# How to hide duplicates of the only field that is shown if other fields are not duplicates

Tags: crystal-reports

If I have a file with 2 fields, and field A can have duplicates, but field B will be all different, I am only showing field A in my report, how do I hide the duplicates from field A? It's not hiding the duplicates, I think because field B are all different values.

ID   VALUE
5     10
6     11
7     12
5     13

I want to hide 5 / 13 because it is a duplicate with the 5 / 10 based on the ID (I am only showing ID in my report)

Comment: Can you show preview how you want display to be? Like showing 5 for the first combination but hiding 5 when 13 is the value?

Comment: I would amend this in the SQL query itself rather than CR.